# MongoDB: How do use aggregation framework to return objectIDs?

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to build a query to return the ObjectId of all accounts that match this criteria:

1. status not equal to -1
2. created_at less than or equal to midnight utc 30 days ago
3. created_at day of month equal to today's day of month

I'm able to do #1 and #2, but am stuck on #3 and also including the ObjectId in the results.

```
Account._get_collection().aggregate([
    { "$match": {
       "status": { "$ne": -1 },
       "created_at": { "$lte": datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0) - datetime.timedelta(days=30), }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "dayOfMonth" : { "$dayOfMonth": "$created_at" },
        },
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "_id": "1"
    }}
])
```

I know the day of month should probably be up in the match section and something needs to be added to the group section for returning ObjectIds.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you please post a sample document from the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the `$group` and `$project` stages as below. You need to keep track of the `Object Ids` of all the records in the group so that you can project it later. So when grouping, use the operator `$push` to accumulate all the object ids per group.

In the `project` stage, just display it.

Your code was incorrect since it was projecting the `"_id"` of each group(the `dayOfMonth`) and not the documents themselves.

```
{ "$group": {
    "_id": {
        "dayOfMonth" : { "$dayOfMonth": "$created_at" },
    },"objectIds":{$push:"$_id"}
}},
{ "$project": {
    "objectIds": 1
}}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. I had to change `"objectIds": "1"` to `"objectIds": 1`.

Comment: Yeah that was a typo.